# Arcpy debug question

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, attributeerror

I'm running this script to iterate through layers, zoom to them, then export each as a pdf but I keep getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_arc_object'
```

I'm not skilled enough at python to interpret this error message.

Here's my code:

```
import arcpy
def zoom_export(zlayer,pdfname,ratio):
    zoom = arcpy.mapping.Layer(zlayer)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(zoom)
    df.extent = zoom.getSelectedExtent()   #zooming to selected feature layer
    df.scale = df.scale * ratio
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    zoomin = arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF("C:\Users\TSPA standard\Desktop\gis\Test.mxd", "TESTPDF")
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(zoom, "CLEAR_SELECTION")

def turn_on(layer,tf,mxd):
    mxd = "C:\Users\TSPA standard\Desktop\gis\Test.mxd"
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
    layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*", df)
    for x in layers:
        if x.name == layer:
            print x.name
            x.visible = tf
            arcpy.RefreshTOC()
            arcpy.RefreshActiveView()



mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Users\TSPA standard\Desktop\gis\Test.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*", df)
for layer in layers:
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(layer,"blah")
    turn_on(layer.name,True,mxd)
    pdfname = layer.name+"PDF"
    zoom_export("blah",pdfname,1.1)
    turn_on(layer.name,False,mxd)
```

Comment: Presenting the whole error message will be helpful if you have any subsequent ArcPy questions.

Comment: You have a confusion in using layer and map document objects. For example in your turn_on def, even though it gets a map document object, you are re assigning mxd to a string which does not make sense. Another example is that in zoom def you are putting a string as layer name i presume and expect arcpy to find this in the given mxd. This is possible if you use CURRENT map document in ArcMap but you need to list layers of mxd first to find out blah if you are using a path to create a map document object.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to export to pdf file a string path to your .mxd file whereas you should be providing the MapDocument object.

```
zoomin = arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF("C:\Users\TSPA standard\Desktop\gis\Test.mxd", "TESTPDF")
```

should be

```
zoomin = arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd_object, "TESTPDF.pdf")
```

Look in the [ExportToPDF](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/exporttopdf.htm) help page

Comment: hmm I'm still getting the same thing
Here's the line that's highlighted in red from the code inspector:

    `def pageLayout(self):
            return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._mxd._arc_object.pageLayout)`

Comment: Install PyScripter and run code in Debugging mode. Execute your code line by line to see which line it breaks and then update your question. https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyscripter/files/PyScripter-v2.6.0-Setup.exe/download